# How to reset database migrations in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am having issues migrating my Django app database on Heroku.

I deleted previous migrations (and they are ignored by git), and whenever I run `python manage.py makemigrations`, I have a previous dependency showing up in the newly created (`001_initial.py`).

Here is what I get in dependencies:

```py
dependencies = [
    ('auth', '0013_auto_20190406_1745'),
]
```

So what happens is that Django does not find those old dependencies in Heroku (it  still works fine locally).

I am looking for a way to **reset** migrations but couldn't find a solution looking into Django doc and online.

I tried deleting the `migrations` folder and running the command `python manage.py myapp zero` but was unsuccessful.

Comment: Did you `git rm` the files, then commit the changes and push to Heroku?

Comment: The files are no longer appear in GitHub. I tried deleted the `.git` folder in case for some reason it was kept in the archive but wasn't successful

Comment: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html

Comment: As mentioned above, I tried deleting migrations (as well as `db.sqlite3`) but migration 013 was still showing up.